# Which is the best one in below cases, creating new variable or just updating parameter variable?

Tags: coding-style

Hi  in below two cases which one is the best code.

You can see I create `PercentW` variable in Case 1. But in Case 2 I am just updating `NewWidth`

Case 1:

```
public static Image ResizeByWidth(Image Img, float NewWidth)
{
    float PercentW = ((float)Img.Width / (float)NewWidth);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(PercentW, (int)(Img.Height / PercentW));
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(Img, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    g.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Case 2:

```
public static Image ResizeByWidth(Image Img, float NewWidth)
{
    NewWidth = ((float)Img.Width / (float)NewWidth);

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(NewWidth, (int)(Img.Height / NewWidth));
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(Img, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    g.Dispose();

    return bmp;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Take the first case, it is more clear.

Comment: And avoid overriding parameters value (like you do in case 2).

Comment: If we're talking about coding style, how about adhering to *java* naming standards (instead of C#)

Comment: @Bohemian that tag was added by Magus see here http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16958457/revisions

Comment: Even so, you will save yourself and everyone else you deal with a lot of confusion if you adhere

Comment: I am not clear with your comment.. But for now I removed java tag. @Bohemian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, the first approach. You should not sacrifice readability over marginal performance gains. (That is, if there are any actual gains at all.)

The only case where this might be violated would be when you have *very convincing reasons* backed up by *real performance measurements* that the other approach performs *significantly* better. That is, you would actually notice slower execution time and/or increased memory usage when sticking with the first approach and the second approach would fix that.

On another note, the second approach **simply doesn't actually work at all**. `NewWidth` would already be overridden with the *percentage* when calling the `Bitmap` constructor, but you want to use the *width* as first argument. You still need the original value of `NewWidth` there, so you'd *still* need to keep that value around in a variable until you call the constructor.

As you can see, you already gave a very good example why you *should* prefer readability over marginal optimizations. In your first approach, you can immediately see that you should pass `NewWidth` (and not `PercentW`) as first argument to `new Bitmap`. In your second approach, those values are mangled up in one variable and you confuse the maintainer (and even yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Doing so:

```
NewWidth = ((float)Img.Width / (float)NewWidth);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(NewWidth, (int)(Img.Height / NewWidth));
```

you could lose a lot of precision due to casting division result to int.

So, the first approach is more correct.

Comment: I updated above code. Now Please confirm me which one is the best code case 1 or 2?

Comment: @Developer in this case they are both equal in mean of their quality

Answer (score 0):

Undoubtably the first case is more clear.

Just think about the next person who will have to maintain your code some time in the future.

Which piece of code is clearer? Easier to understand? Less prone to misunderstanding or bugs?